# Is the twisted symmetric fifth power $L$-function holomorphic?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

Let $\pi$ be a Maass cusp form for SL($2,\mathbb Z$). Let $\omega$ be a primitive Dirichlet character.

Let us consider the $L-$ function
$$L(s,Sym^5 \pi \times \omega)$$ or $L(s,Sym^6 \pi \times \omega)$ or $L(s,Sym^7 \pi \times \omega)$ or $L(s,Sym^8 \pi \times \omega)$.

Are they known to be holomorphic on the whole complex plane?

Comment: Surely not. These sorts of results are only recently established in the holomorphic case and the techniques used there (Galois representations) won't generalise (for now at least).

Comment: Hi Eric, but Galois representations are not the only method to treat $L$-functions. How about Langlands-Shahidi method? Do they includes any one of these cases? BTW, I would like to see your reference for modular forms.

Comment: Symm^5 is way out of reach using any method other than the automorphy lifting theorem techniques. Look at recent papers by Clozel and Thorne for the holomorphic case.

Comment: For holomorphic forms this was proved in BarnetLamb-Harris-Geraghty-Taylor: A family of Calabi-Yau varieties and potential automorphy II. More precisely, they proved automorphy of the $L$-function apart from finitely many Euler factors.

Comment: @7-adic:  Nope -- $Sym^5$ and higher are out of range of Langlands-Shahidi. Basically getting up to $Sym^4$ requires some special cases of Levi subgroups in exceptional groups, and sadly the special cases run out.  Garland has a long-term program to try to extend these methods to infinite-dimensional groups -- if one is allowed to use Kac-Moody groups, one could go further.  But alas, the results in that direction are not nearly strong enough for $Sym^5$ L-functions as far as I know.

Comment: Following up on @Marty's comment: in the 80s, several people, including PiateskiShapiro-Rallis, myself, and others, tried to identify what sort of Rankin-Selberg situation could produce such "higher" L-functions... tentatively thinking in terms of "generalized groups"... but/and found that (at least it seemed at the time) there was no sane "generalized group" recipe that could produce a given L-function "at will". Maybe there has been progress, but it is already not so easy to make a reductive "group" with arbitrarily specified Coxeter group as "Weyl group"... Such obstacles.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an open problem.

For a very recent reference of $Sym^m\pi$ being known only for $m \leq 4$ ($\pi$ arbitrary cuspidal), see:

- Huixue Lao, Mark McKee, Yangbo Ye, [Asymptotics for cuspidal representations by functoriality from $GL(2)$](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.01208.pdf) (2015)

As eric mentions in the comments, arithmetic techniques make some cases like holomorphic forms accesible, but those techniques are certenly missing in this case, $\pi$ a Maass form.

Also, more concretely for Maass forms, see this paragraph on a 2003 Sarnak paper ([Spectra of Hyperbolic Surfaces](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2003-40-04/S0273-0979-03-00991-1/S0273-0979-03-00991-1.pdf)):

> This [Kim-Sarnak result towards the eigenvalue conjecture for Maass
>   forms] is getting close to $1/4$, but it is also close to the limit of
>   these methods. The functorial lifts $sym^3$ and $sym^4$ are based on
>   the continuous spectrum (Eisenstein series) on exceptional groups
>   including $E_8$. What can be done this way terminates with the finite
>   list of exceptional groups.

This is closely related with what Marty and Garret said in their very interesting comments above.